# Filter nested object properties based on value

Tags: javascript, object, filter

Consider the following data:

```js
const state = {
  tasks: {
    'ID1': {
      name: "Go to shop",
      completed: false,
    },
    'ID2': {
      name: "Get bananas",
      completed: true,
    },
    'ID3': {
      name: "Get apples",
      completed: false,
    }
  }
}
```

To retrieve only the tasks that have `completed` set to `true` the follwoing code can be used:

```js
function getCompletedTasks(state) {
  let tasks = {}

  Object.keys(state.tasks).forEach((key) => {
    let task = state.tasks[key]

    if (task.completed) tasks[key] = task
  })

  return tasks
}
```

I was wondering if there's a better way than manually creating a new `array` with `let tasks = {}`? I've looked at `map` but I'm not really sure this can help. I'm a newbie, just trying to understand if there's a cleaner better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` to get an array of entries, filter it by whether the value's `completed` property is truthy, then turn it back into an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const state = {
  tasks: {
    'ID1': {
      name: "Go to shop",
      completed: false,
    },
    'ID2': {
      name: "Get bananas",
      completed: true,
    },
    'ID3': {
      name: "Get apples",
      completed: false,
    }
  }
}

function getCompletedTasks(state) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(state.tasks).filter(([, val]) => val.completed)
  );
}

console.log(getCompletedTasks(state));
```

Comment: Awesome! That was exaxtly what I was looking for. Didn't know that feature existed. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does this part mean `[, val]` ? Why is there an extra comma needed?

Comment: `Object.entries` gives you an array of entries. An entry is a key and a value in an array, eg `[[key1, val1], [key2, val2]]`. When iterating over an entry, we only want to consider the value, so the key (which would be before the first comma) is not put into a variable, because it'd only add noise.